# Converting sql/oracle to java mongodb query

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new in Mongodb. can anybody tell me any online tool where i can easily convert my sql/ oracle query in mongodb for my java  code.
 ex:

Simple oracle query:

select * form student where class = "XII" and name="John";

MongoDb Query for java:

```
db.getCollection("Student", Student.class).find(and(eq("class" , "XII"), eq("name", "John"))).into(new ArrayList<Employee>());
```

so i want a query builder for java where i can pass the sql/oracle query and i will get Java code for mongodb as Output.

Please suggest some useful .

Comment: It will be better if you use [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) to convert your sql query to Mongo. Also there are some websites that provides online conversion of SQL queries to Mongo. You can implement these queries with your native language driver like here in Java.

Comment: I dont want from sql to mongo. i want sql to java mongo code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if there is any converter available but I will suggest you to learn it by this best free quick course

https://university.mongodb.com/courses/MongoDB/M101J/

Comment: by clicking above URL getting 

404: "Page not found"